# Can I move a symfony2 directory or host after caches have been created?

Tags: caching, deployment, symfony

**The question:**

Are sf2 caches directory-independent? Ie: Can I do `cache:clear` in a certain dir and then move the project dir to another machine/directory without breaking the caches?

**The scenario:**

- We have an application based on Symfony2.
- The production machine has 500MB.
- We currently deploy by uploading the soft and then clearing the caches.
- In the production machine, `app/console cache:clear` lasts about 5 mins to be generated.
- In a devel-machine with 2GB it lasts just a few seconds.

We have a requirement to minimize time-to-production. 5 mins waiting the caches is too much.

We thought about running the `cache:clear` in a local machine and then upload the product to production with the caches already generated. The local paths of the project (/home/ubuntu/devel/...) are different to the production paths (/var/www) and cannot be tuned to be the same.

Comment: But isn't the site usable while the cache is being warmed up? If yes then time-to-production is not as long as you say.

Comment: Yep.  For the most part the site will keep right on running just fine.  You could also just delete cache/prod then rebuild the cache completely which should only take a few seconds.

Comment: @greg0ire, I don't know if it is sure to run live in parallel while cache is being warmed. Is there any docs about concurrent usage of the web can cache:clear?

Comment: @Cerad, yes, that's the problem: In my local machine, deleting cache/prod and calling cache:clear lasts 5 to 10 secs, but in production, as the RAM is only 500MB lasts many minutes to do that. That what you propose is what ye are currently doing and what we want to do faster, so we though about doing the operation in another fast machine, then copy it already warmed-up into the slow machine.

Comment: @XaviMontero: I don't think there should be any problem with running live while the cache is being warmed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Symfony2 cache uses absolute paths in various places, so you can't copy the cache from one machine to the other, if the paths differ.

What you are really looking for is deployment via capifony. Upon deployment it creates a new folder on your live machine, prepares the new version of your project in that folder (includes publishing assets, clearing the cache and so on) and then simply switches the old folder with the new folder.

As a certain number of old versions is kept on the live server, you can even do a rollback if you have to.

And you can build a nifty one click deployment with capifony and Jenkins CI ;)

Comment: Thanks Pierre for the info about absolute paths. Any source/resource on that info? - About using capifony, yes our current deployer is custom but is much like capifony, and really it does the clean-up in the prod machine and then makes the cache:clear; but as the prod machine has only 500MB RAM it takes many minutes what in devel machines are 5 or 10 secs. This is why we wanted to "pre-calculate" the caches and move them pre-warmed. - Any URL or pointer on the tip that the caches contain absolute paths?

Comment: Resource are the files in the cache folder ;) You will find multiple hits when you grep for your absolute symfony2 root inside those files. As greg0ire and Cerad already stated, your site is still useable during the clearing of the cache. If I remember right, the cache:clear task creates a new folder, creates the new cache files, and finally swaps old cache folder with the new one.